# Almost sure convergence, while convergence of series of expected values is given

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

Suppose, that $\mathbb{H}^{2}$ is the space of all predictable stochastic processes X, such that: $||X||^{2}_{\mathbb{H}} = \mathbb{E} \left[ \int_{0}^{T} |X_{t}|^{2} dt\right] < \infty$.

We have the sequence of stochastic processes $(Y^{k})_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$, which satisfies following assumptions:

1. $Y^{k}$ convergences to Y in $\mathbb{H}^{2}$.
2. $\sum_{k} ||Y^{k+1} - Y_{k}||^{2}_{\mathbb{H}} < \infty$

Now the question is that if under these assumptions $Y^{k}$ converges to $Y$ almost sure?

In other words, how can I proof the almost sure convergence of the solution of backward stochastic differential equation (corollary 2.1 from http://horst.qfl-berlin.de/files/ElKaroui-Peng-Quenez-BSDEinFinance.pdf)

Comment: The proof is about convergence in $\mathbb{H}^{2}$, isn't it (I could be wrong)? My question is how can I proof the a.s. convergence from the convergence of this given series

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "a.s. convergence"? $Y_k(t) \to Y(t)$ almost surely for each fixed $t$?

Comment: Yes, I think so.

Comment: in general, the assertion does not hold true...